# Pagination, filter, sort on postgres JSON

Tags: postgresql, go-gorm

I have DB structure like here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wRJavCjXLzYWuCvLoTAzHG/0

```
CREATE TABLE machine (
    date_time timestamp,
    data text
);

INSERT INTO machine (date_time, data) VALUES (NOW(), '{`A-Value`: 12, `A-Type`: `BB`, `B-Value`: 220, `B-Type`: `FF`}');

INSERT INTO machine (date_time, data) VALUES (NOW() + INTERVAL '1 day', '{`A-Value`: 4243, `A-Type`: `BB`, `B-Value`: 43530, `B-Type`: `FF`}');

INSERT INTO machine (date_time, data) VALUES (NOW()+ INTERVAL '2 day', '{`A-Value`: 5652, `A-Type`: `BB`, `B-Value`: 687, `B-Type`: `FF`}');
```

I must paginate, sort and/or filter it. I know how to paginate filter and sort over `date_time` column. But I do not know how to do it over `data`. For example, I want to filter/sort over `-Type` and still I have to return only `2` rows if `Limit` is `2`.

I have tried `json_each` with subquery but this function accept only one row not a range. Maybe someone solve something similar.

Comment: Well, your sample data isn't valid JSON, so the built-in JSON functions won't work with it.

Comment: `::json` can do trick. Still I do not know how to handle the rest

Comment: No, your sample data can not be cast to JSON. https://dbfiddle.uk/n692_IUp

Answer (score 0):

First you have to replace the ` by " for both the json keys and string values.:

```
CREATE TABLE machine (
    date_time timestamp,
    data jsonb
);
INSERT INTO machine (date_time, data) VALUES (NOW(), '{"A-Value": 12, "A-Type": "BB", "B-Value": 220, "B-Type": "FF"}');
INSERT INTO machine (date_time, data) VALUES (NOW() + INTERVAL '1 day', '{"A-Value": 4243, "A-Type": "BB", "B-Value": 43530, "B-Type": "FF"}');
INSERT INTO machine (date_time, data) VALUES (NOW()+ INTERVAL '2 day', '{"A-Value": 5652, "A-Type": "BB", "B-Value": 687, "B-Type": "FF"}');
```

Then you can filter on the json value associated to the key "A-Type" with a WHERE clause, sort on the value associated to the "A-Value" with an ORDER clause and use the LIMIT clause at the end. For instance :

```
SELECT *
  FROM machine
 WHERE data->>'A-Type' = 'BB'
 ORDER BY data->'A-Value'
 LIMIT 2
```

UPDATE : you can also filter over all the keys similar to "-Type" with the following query based on jsonb path functions and regular expressions :

```
SELECT *
  FROM machine
 WHERE jsonb_path_exists(data, '$.keyvalue() ? (@.key like_regex "-Type$" && @.value == "BB")')
 ORDER BY data->'A-Value'
 LIMIT 2
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SKw9Fz4W)

Comment: And when I want to filter over all `-Type`s I can have it more than `A` and `B`?

Comment: Yes it is possible but a bit more tricky, see the update